# How to write $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^n$ in terms of $n$, when $n$ is a positive integer.

Tags: matrices

How can I write this in terms of $n$? If I do some basic multiplication, when $n=2$, the matrix is \begin{pmatrix} 10 & -1 & 7 \\ 6 & 5 & 5 \\ 6 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix} I see no pattern here... but I have been told there is a way to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: I understand now how I can use that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you diagonalize the matrix, you'll see that

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & -2 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)=
\underbrace{\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & -11 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 14 \\
\end{array}
\right)}_{\textrm{eigenvectors in columns}}
\underbrace{\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)}_{\textrm{eigenvalues}}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & -11 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 14 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
$$
and so,

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & -2 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)^n=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & -11 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 14 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)^n
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & -11 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 14 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
$$

After some elementary calculations, the nth power of the matrix is given by

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2^{n-1} \left(2^n+1\right) & \frac{1}{30} \left(22 (-1)^n-25\ 2^n+3\ 4^n\right) &
   \frac{1}{15} \left(-11 (-1)^n+5\ 2^n+3\ 2^{2 n+1}\right) \\
 2^{n-1} \left(2^n-1\right) & \frac{1}{30} \left(2 (-1)^n+25\ 2^n+3\ 4^n\right) &
   \frac{1}{15} \left((-1)^{n+1}-5\ 2^n+3\ 2^{2 n+1}\right) \\
 2^{n-1} \left(2^n-1\right) & \frac{1}{30} \left(-28 (-1)^n+25\ 2^n+3\ 4^n\right) &
   \frac{1}{15} \left(14 (-1)^n-5\ 2^n+3\ 2^{2 n+1}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

(did not try to simplify, I obtained directly from Wolfram)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. If you can’t quickly spot a pattern, the conventional approach is to diagonalize the matrix, i.e., write it in the form $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal, and then use the fact that $A^n = P\Lambda^nP^{-1}$. I suspect that’s the method that you’re expected to use for this exercise.

Since you’ve already computed $A^2$, however, you can avoid all of that tedious eigenvector finding and matrix inversion by using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. If $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, we can write $x^n=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$, where $r$ has degree strictly less than $p$. Then $A^n=p(A)q(A)+r(A)$, but by C-H $p(A)=0$, therefore $A^n=r(A)$. The characteristic polynomial of your matrix is cubic, which means that $A^n=aI+bA+cA^2$ for some unknown scalars $a$, $b$ and $c$. It turns out that this equation is also satisfied by any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, so you can find the unknown coefficients by substituting each eigenvalue into $a+b\lambda+c\lambda^2=\lambda^n$ and solving the resulting system of linear equations.

The eigenvalues of this matrix are simple—all have algebraic multiplicity one—so there’s another option available. If $x$ is a right eigenvector of $A$ with simple eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $y$ a corresponding left eigenvector (i.e., a right eigenvector of $A^T$), then the matrix ${xy^T\over x^Ty}$ represents a projection onto $x$ that maps eigenvectors with eigenvalue not equal to $\lambda$ to zero. Let $P_i$ be the projection that corresponds to $\lambda_i$. We can then decompose $A$ into $\lambda_1P_1+\lambda_2P_2+\lambda_3P_3$, and since $P_i^2=P_i$ and $P_i P_j=0$ when $i\ne j$, we have $A^n=\lambda_1^nP_1+\lambda_2^nP_2+\lambda_3^nP_3$. I don’t think that this is really any less work than just diagonalizing the matrix, but the computations involved are a bit simpler to perform.

Comment: I was supposed to use the form A=PAP^{−1} for this specific problem. Found that C-H was also a very clean alternative that I had never thought of using. Thank you for your help!